# Ignore the parameter if the user not entered value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am using SSRS to build a report and connecting to sql server db

lets assume that I have the following table:

```
ID : CITY    : DATE        : AMOUNT 
01 : London  : 2019-01-01  : 12
02 : New York: 2019-02-01  : 15
03 : London  : 2019-01-05  : 25
04 : London  : 2019-01-07  : 30
```

I am Using the following query to get the report and pass a value to **city** parameter

```
select id , city , date , amount
from table
where city = @city
```

if the user pass "New York" the report will be like the following

```
ID : CITY    : DATE        : AMOUNT 
02 : New York: 2019-02-01  : 15
```

My question is How can I make the parameter is not mandatory which means if the user not pass "New York" the result should be like

```
ID : CITY    : DATE        : AMOUNT 
01 : London  : 2019-01-01  : 12
02 : New York: 2019-02-01  : 15
03 : London  : 2019-01-05  : 25
04 : London  : 2019-01-07  : 30
```

Comment: `where (city = @city or @city is null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put another condition in your query that is true for all records if the the parameter is `null`:

```
select id, city, date, amount
from your_table
where @city is null 
   or @city = city
```

Comment: Not working if I am using a data-set to get city information from table of city

Comment: Make sure the parameter is `null` and not an empty string`''`

Comment: i am usuing dropdownlist for the parameter so i have to union a null to the dropdownlist

select city from table
union
select null

it works now